# d3 X Axis Scale in Time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time

I have data in time domain. Data are coming 30secs intervals normally. But sometimes device is turned off and next data will come 1 day later.

I want same distances between data points(not jump or scale the graph). Even time was jumped to the next day or next year, I want to see the graph without scale.

I add only one data point to the graph (15 hours between last two data) and all graph is compressed to the left side as you can see from the picture.

[image]

```js
< script >

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 50
    },
    width = window.innerWidth - 100,
    height = window.innerHeight - 90;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the 1st line
var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.current);
  });

// define the 2nd line
var valueline2 = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.intend);
  });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data

d3.json("<?php echo "
    getGraphData.php ? id = ".$id." & type = ".$type; ?>",
    function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      // format the data
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        d.close = +d.current;
        d.open = +d.intend;
      });


      // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      if (<?php echo $type ?> == 1) {
        y.domain([
          d3.min(data, function(d) {
            if (Math.min(d.close, d.open) < 15) {
              return Math.min(d.close, d.open);
            } else {
              return 15;
            }
          }),
          d3.max(data, function(d) {
            if (Math.max(d.close, d.open) > 30) {
              return Math.max(d.close, d.open);
            } else {
              return 30;
            }
          })
        ]);
      }

      if (<?php echo $type ?> == 2) {
        y.domain([
          d3.min(data, function(d) {
            return 0;
          }),
          d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return 100;
          })
        ]);
      }

      // Add the valueline path.
      svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline);

      // Add the valueline2 path.
      svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("d", valueline2);

      // Add the X Axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .style("font-family", "\"Segoe UI\", Arial, sans-serif")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // Add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g")
        .style("font-family", "\"Segoe UI\", Arial, sans-serif")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I handle it with these

```js
var n = 300;

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, n - 1]) // input
  .range([0, width]); // output

// define the 1st line
var valueline2 = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(n - i);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.current);
  });

// define the 2nd line
var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(n - i);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.intend);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your last paragraph is not clear, can you edit the question and explain a bit and make it more clear?

Comment: I add more clear image. Thank you

Comment: You mean you don't want the displacement in x-axis if there is a time gap? When why use a time graph? Use a normal graph where x-axis is set to index of entries.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think, its a same graph, only matter is scaling in here. Also I want to see timestamps under the axis. I am not good at php or js. I am trying to edit the code. Could you help me.